# Converting Python 2 to 3 with Encryption Function

Tags: python, encryption, cmd, tcp, decode

The script was written for Python 2 but I need to convert it to Python 3. When I do, it throws my this error "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes"

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "tplink_smartplug.py", line 105, in <module>
       sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd))
   File "tplink_smartplug.py", line 70, in encrypt
       result += chr(a)
```

### TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

```
# XOR Autokey Cipher with starting key = 171
def encrypt(string):
    key = 171
    result = pack('>I', len(string))
    for i in string:
        a = key ^ ord(i)
        key = a
        result += chr(a)   #line70
    return result

def decrypt(string):
    key = 171
    result = ""
    for i in string:
        a = key ^ ord(i)
        key = ord(i)
        result += chr(a)
    return result
```

---

```
# Send command and receive reply
try:
    sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock_tcp.connect((ip, port))
    sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd))    #line105
    data = sock_tcp.recv(2048)
    sock_tcp.close()

    print(("Sent:     ", cmd ))
    print(("Received: ", decrypt(data[4:]) ))
except socket.error:
    quit("Cound not connect to host " + ip + ":" + str(port))
```

Comment: try `result += chr(a).encode()` or `result += bytes( [a] )`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has been revised for Python3 at [GITHUB](https://github.com/softScheck/tplink-smartplug/pull/25/files)